# Integrate System.Data.SQLite.dll with Unity

Tags: c#, sqlite, mono, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to integrate the System.Data.SQLite dll (with SQLite.Interop) to my project because Mono.SQLite is really limited (no password, no backup database...).

But can't make it work I always get DllNotFoundException on SQLite.Interop.Dll.

Should I build SQLite.Interop for Win32 and System.Data.SQLite for .NET 2.0 ? or Unity 3.5 with full subset ?
I've tried both without success and can't find any article on google on how to integrate it.

The FAQ is pretty short : https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/faq.wiki#q6

Should I use "Precompiled Binaries for Mono on POSIX (.NET Framework 4.5.1)" ? But I though Unity only supported 2.0 version of .NET ? or the .NET 2.0 precompiled files ?

Thank you,